# Android Vertical Scrollview Out of Memory Error

Tags: android, out-of-memory, scrollview, lazy-loading, vertical-scrolling

I am creating an Android app (Android Studio) which displays a vertical scroll view that contains many textviews and imageviews (around 40 on one page). See below for the .xml file. This code only shows 3 of these repeating patterns but my code contains many more - removed these to reduce the length of this post.

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/smiles_background"
    tools:context="com.mobilewebanalytiq.forkshappyhour.monday">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Search by Day"
        android:id="@+id/tvnumber"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Monday"
        android:id="@+id/tvday"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView401"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView401"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/sunday1" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView402"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView402"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/sunday2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView403"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView403"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/sunday3" />
            
            //This will continue on for many lines
            
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

As expected, the app will crash when I open this page. What is the best way to redesign this .xml so that the app no longer crashes? Should I used a different layout or is there a way to optimize this code? As you can see, I am pulling from @drawable folder, but maybe using another location would help. The .java file is below for reference. Your detailed help is appreciated!

```css
package com.mobilewebanalytiq.forkshappyhour;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;


/**
 * Created by Matt on 2/8/2015.
 */
public class monday extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.monday);


    }}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a listview instead of a scrollview? Your `OutOfMemory` error is because of the bitmaps your imageviews are using.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a `ListView` so that all of your images do not load immediately and items "recycle"

Even so, you may have problems. Your `drawables` are probably too large, either way. You should look into loading them based on the size that is needed for display. See this from the Android docs:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

With the limited memory available you will not be able to have a direct reference to each of the images, otherwise like you say you will run out of memory. These images will take up space in memory as long as there is a reference to your BitMap objects. To free up this memory you need to dereference these BitMaps and or clear the ArrayList, this will allow the Garbage Collector to free up the unused memory. Ideally you only want a reference only to the images you can see, or the ones you will see next.

You could just look up the 8 images for every page view, or perhaps the the images in the surrounding page views. If the images you are display are much larger than the size they take up then you may want to resize these images on the fly and only store them as the size they appear, this should also help reduce the memory footprint of your images.

The Android developers have written a series of tutorials on just this topic: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html